# How to continue iteration of JSON object/list with "for" loop nested in another "for" loop?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to iterate through a JSON object/list to get the prices from the list. It works fine for the first "for" loop, but then for my program I need to have another "for" loop nested inside the first loop that effectively continues iterating again where the first loop left off.

edit: I apologise as I probably wasn't very clear as why I'm structuring this code this way. It probably isn't the best solution as I'm not very experienced with python but I'm trying to simulate the looping flow of price data based on historical prices from this JSON. So when the price is equal to something in the first loop, I was trying to continue the flow of data from where the last loop left off (the last price it read) in a nested loop with different if statements, now that the first one has been triggered. I understand this is probably a very poor way of getting around this problem and I'd be happy to hear suggestions on how to do it in a much simpler way.

```py
for i in json:
    time.sleep(1)
    price = i['p']

    if price == "0.00000183":
        print("foo")

        for i in json:
            time.sleep(1)
            price = float(i['p'])
            if price == "0.00000181":
                print("sold")
            else:
                continue

    elif price == "0.00000185":
        print ("sold")
        break

    else:
        continue
```

Example segment of the JSON list:

```
[
    {
        "a":4886508,
        "p":"0.00000182",
        "q":"10971.00000000",
        "f":5883037,
        "l":5883037,
        "T":1566503952430,
        "m":1,
        "M":1
    },
    {
        "a":4886509,
        "p":"0.00000182",
        "q":"10971.00000000",
        "f":5883038,
        "l":5883038,
        "T":1566503953551,
        "m":1,
        "M":1
    },
    {
        "a":4886510,
        "p":"0.00000182",
        "q":"10971.00000000",
        "f":5883039,
        "l":5883039,
        "T":1566503954431,
        "m":1,
        "M":1
    }
]
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use a `continue` statement instead of another for loop? If you explain why you want to reiterate over the list, we could probably help you avoid another loop.

Comment: Why would you need to do something like this? It's really weird, and it indicates that you probably either haven't fully understood the problem that you're attempting to solve, or you haven't understood the language syntax. Or it makes perfect sense in context, but you haven't given us the context. Please explain the use case for this algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

You have 3 nested dicts inside the list and you’re using one value `price` to store all 3; therefore overwriting the value for every iteration.

I suggest using a list comprehension to get the price for each sub-dict.

```
[i['p'] for i in json]
```

This results in:

```
['0.00000182', '0.00000182', '0.00000182']
```

Although as a forewarning there is a builtin module called `json` so should you want to use that in the future you will need to use a more descriptive name; as well as your other naming conventions are very non informative in the first place consider better conventions.

P.S the price values are strings thus it’s meaningless to compare to int’s

Answer (score 1):

Apologies guys, I should've made it more clear that what I was looking for was probably simpler than what I made it out to be or how I described it. I basically just wanted to continue the second loop from where the first left off, with something like this which I have now found to be an alright solution.

```py
elementCount = 0
for i in json:
    time.sleep(1)
    price = i['p']
    elementCount = elementCount + 1

    if price == "0.00000183":
        print("foo")

        for i in json[elementCount:]:
            time.sleep(1)
            price = float(i['p'])
            if price == "0.00000181":
                print("sold")
            else:
                continue

    elif price == "0.00000185":
        print ("sold")
        break

    else:
        continue
```

I basically just didn't understand the format for continuing the iteration from a certain element in the list, like this [40:]. Thanks for all your answers and help.

Answer (score 0):

### Use `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
```

- The question was how do I iterate through a `json`

  - I think the real question and goal is, how do I access my data from this object and gather insight from it.
  - That's the power of `pandas`.  Now all of the information is available and easy to use.

#### If the data is inside a file, just as it's shown:

```
df = pd.read_json('file.json')
```

#### If the data is just a named object (e.g. `data = [{...}, {...}, {...}]`)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

#### Output of `df`:

[image]

#### Get `p`, or any of the other information:

```
p_list = df.p.tolist()
print(p_list)

>>> ['0.00000182', '0.00000182', '0.00000182']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code doesn't make much sense, so it's not clear what you're try to accomplish.

Ignoring that, if you use [`json.load()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) to read your file, the result will be a Python list of dictionaries (which are equivalent to JSON `object`s). Afterwards you can then just iterate through this list — you don't need to do anything else to go to the next dictionary/object.

Within each dictionary/object you can randomly access the key/value pairs it contains. If yoy want to iterate over them for some reason, you can used `obj.keys()`, `obj.values()`, or `obj.items()`, as you can with any dictionary.

Here's a small example of what I'm saying:

```
import json

filename = 'list_sample.json'

with open(filename) as json_file:
    object_list = json.load(json_file)

for obj in object_list:
    if obj['p'] == "0.00000183":
        print("foo")
        price = float(obj['p'])
        print(price)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write two loops using the same iterator object. You just need to create the iterator from your `json` list of dictionaries:

```
iterator = iter(json_data)
for i in iterator:
    # stuff

    for j in iterator: # start looping from where we left off
        ... # more stuff
```

Note that this only makes sense if the inner loop will be interrupted at some point by a `break` statement. Otherwise it will consume all of the iterator's contents and the outer loop will have nothing left. If you were expecting that, you should probably just break out of the outer loop and write the (formerly) inner loop at the same level:

```
for i in iterator:
    if something():
        break

for j in iterator: # iterate over the rest of the iterator's values
    ...
```

Note that I used `json_data` in my example code, rather than your variable name `json`. Using `json` as a variable name may be a bad idea because it may be the name of the module you're using to parse your data. Reusing the name may get confusing (`json = json.load(filename)` for instance can only be run once).